# Count the number of occurences of each number in a random array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, integer

I am writing a code that makes an array of 100 integers filled with random integers. Then it will count the occurrence of each integer and print them out as shown:

```
1 occurs 1 time
2 occurs 15 times
3 occurs 9 times
etc...
```

The problem with my code is that I am getting weird counts. For example, 10's occurrence is 100 but that is not possible. Sometimes some integers are not counted at all.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int arr[100];

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        arr[i] = rand() % (10 - 1 + 1) + 1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        cout<< arr[i]<<" ";
    }

    int count = 0;

    cout<<" " << endl;

    for(int x = 0; x <= 10; x++){

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            if (x == arr[i])
                count++;

        cout<< x << " occurs " << count << " times"<< endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to reset `count` before starting the inner `for` loop.

Comment: Print `count` at the beginning of the "x loop".

Comment: `10 - 1 + 1` is a surprising way of writing `10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look carefully at the output, you will notice that `count` never decreases.
This is because you declared it outside the loop and then only increment it.
(So the "count" of the largest number in the array will always be the size of the array.)

Move the counter inside the loop, into the context of the `x` that it's counting:

```
for(int x = 0; x <= 10; x++){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an array to store count for every value in your original array.

```
//int count = 0;    // use array instead
int count[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    count[i] = 0;
}

cout << " " << endl;

//for (int x = 0; x <= 10; x++) // x cannot be zero due to you add 1 to every random value
for (int x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        if (x == arr[i])
            count[x - 1]++;

    cout << x << " occurs " << count[x - 1] << " times" << endl;
}
```